# Detect touch on UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, touch, sprite-kit

I have a node that acts like an UIButton and a node that performs an action when the screen gets touched.
The problem is that the lion jump action does not get fired.
In addition: both names of the nodes are correct.

My code for the UIEvent:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode: self];
        SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

        UITouch *lionTouch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint locationLion = [lionTouch locationInView:[self view]];
        SKNode *lionNode = [self nodeAtPoint:locationLion];

        if ([lionNode.name isEqualToString:@"veggieLion"]) {
            if (!lionIsJumping) {
                [self lionJump];

                lionIsJumping = YES;
            }
        }

        if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"repalyButton"]) {
            // Button action
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you logging to see whether either node meets the isEqualToString condition?

Comment: Yes. It fires when I touch nearby the lionNode.

Comment: And are you sure lionIsJumping is false? Can you post more of your code? The action and where the Boolean is set to false

Answer (score 0):

[Apple documentation for SKNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) says the method `nodeAtPoint` "*Returns the deepest descendant that intersects a point.*"

I've had this trouble in the past. where the method would return the SKSpriteNode that I had used for the background, even if I were definitely tapping the target sprite/node!

Since you are checking for two nodes, I would approach it in the following way:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode: self];

  SKNode * lionNode = [self childNodeWithName:@"veggieLion"];
  SKNode * replayButton = [self childNodeWithName:@"repalyButton"];

  if ([self.lionNode containsPoint:location]) {
    if (!lionIsJumping) {
      [self lionJump];
      lionIsJumping = YES;
    }
    return;
  }

  if ([self.replayButton containsPoint:location]) {
    // Button action
    return;
  }

  /* test for other targets */
}
```